# Unable to backup after recovery model change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Previously I had the recovery model as `SIMPLE`. I have altered it to `FULL`.

While trying to perform `BACKUP LOG`, I am getting an error saying

> BACKUP LOG cannot be performed because there is no current database backup.

How can I get the backup of transaction logs?

Comment: you need to perform a FULL Backup first

Comment: How to do that ?

Comment: use BACKUP DATABASE command. Refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx to syntax

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you have 3 forms of backup: `Full`, `Differential` and `Log`:

- The `Full` backup is the most important because it has all the information of the database.
- The `differential` is the diference of the last full backup until now.
- The `Log` is the diference of the last full or differential backup until now.

So you can have just the `Full` Backup or `Full` and `Diferrential` or `Full` and `Log` or `Full`, `Differential` and `Log` backups. You choose the best combination for your need.

Also look for the `recovery/nonrecovery` option in the `restore` clause